# Pandas - iterating with nested for-loop in a dataframe

Tags: for-loop, pandas, iteration

I have some data that I need to iterate multipliers over.  In essence I have three parameters that need to be applied at a High(=1) Medium(=0) and Low(=-1) level.
The value of the parameters that are iterated are:

```
par = 0.25
Skew = 0.20
TS = 0.1
```

I need to iterate over every combination of p,t and s where each of them are in[-1,0,1]

```
25% Par     -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1   0   0   0   0  0   0   0   0   0    1   1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1
20% Skew    -1  -1  -1   0   0   0   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   0  0   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  0   0   0   1   1   1
10% TS      -1   0   1  -1   0   1  -1   0   1  -1  0    1  -1  0   1   -1  0   1   -1   0  1   -1  0   1   -1  0   1
```

I have been able to get the desired results for p,t,s at permutation(1,1,1) which is the last one in the nested for-loop, i just need to be able to do this for each permutation and also have the particular permutation that was applied be included.  I think I am close . . .but that gets me nowhere.

```
In [3]:

df
Out[3]:
   Quant    Vol
0     13  30.00
1      4  27.50
2    -19  26.00
3     14  23.50
4      4  21.00
5     18  20.00
6     -1  19.00
7     16  18.50
8     -5  18.75
9    -18  19.00
In [4]:

df['par']=.25
df['skew']=.2
df['TS']=.1
In [5]:

df
Out[5]:
   Quant    Vol   par  skew   TS
0     13  30.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
1      4  27.50  0.25   0.2  0.1
2    -19  26.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
3     14  23.50  0.25   0.2  0.1
4      4  21.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
5     18  20.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
6     -1  19.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
7     16  18.50  0.25   0.2  0.1
8     -5  18.75  0.25   0.2  0.1
9    -18  19.00  0.25   0.2  0.1
In [6]:

    for p in [-1,0,1]:
        df['p'] =p
        for s in [-1,0,1]:
            df['s'] = s
            for t in [-1,0,1]:
                df['t'] = t
In [7]:

def iterate(df):
    df['Mod_Vol'] = df['Vol']*(1+df['par']*p)*(1+df['skew']*s)*(1+df['TS']*t)
    return(df)
In [8]:

df = df.groupby([df['Vol']]).apply(iterate)
In [9]:

df
Out[9]:
   Quant    Vol   par  skew   TS  p  s  t  Mod_Vol
0     13  30.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  49.5000
1      4  27.50  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  45.3750
2    -19  26.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  42.9000
3     14  23.50  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  38.7750
4      4  21.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  34.6500
5     18  20.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  33.0000
6     -1  19.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  31.3500
7     16  18.50  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  30.5250
8     -5  18.75  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  30.9375
9    -18  19.00  0.25   0.2  0.1  1  1  1  31.3500
```

I need to have each one of these values of vol calculated 27 times and I need to have a value called "Scenario" that contains the identifier of the specific permutation of p,s,t (for example permutation #6 is p=-1,s=0,t=1) so that I can later examine the scenario that gives the greatest impact below are the first 2 values of Vol to illustrate the desired outcome (generated in excel):

```
Scenario    Quant   Vol     par     skew    TS      p       s       t       Mod_Vol
        1   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   16.20
        2   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   0.00    18.00
        3   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   1.00    19.80
        4   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    -1.00   20.25
        5   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    0.00    22.50
        6   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    1.00    24.75
        7   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    -1.00   24.30
        8   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    0.00    27.00
        9   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    1.00    29.70
       10   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   -1.00   21.60
       11   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   0.00    24.00
       12   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   1.00    26.40
       13   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    -1.00   27.00
       14   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    30.00
       15   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    1.00    33.00
       16   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    -1.00   32.40
       17   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    0.00    36.00
       18   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    1.00    39.60
       19   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   -1.00   27.00
       20   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   0.00    30.00
       21   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   1.00    33.00
       22   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    -1.00   33.75
       23   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    0.00    37.50
       24   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    1.00    41.25
       25   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    -1.00   40.50
       26   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    0.00    45.00
       27   13.00   30.00   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    1.00    49.50
        1   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   14.85
        2   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   0.00    16.50
        3   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   -1.00   1.00    18.15
        4   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    -1.00   18.56
        5   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    0.00    20.63
        6   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   0.00    1.00    22.69
        7   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    -1.00   22.28
        8   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    0.00    24.75
        9   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    -1.00   1.00    1.00    27.23
       10   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   -1.00   19.80
       11   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   0.00    22.00
       12   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    -1.00   1.00    24.20
       13   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    -1.00   24.75
       14   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    27.50
       15   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    0.00    1.00    30.25
       16   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    -1.00   29.70
       17   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    0.00    33.00
       18   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    0.00    1.00    1.00    36.30
       19   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   -1.00   24.75
       20   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   0.00    27.50
       21   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    -1.00   1.00    30.25
       22   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    -1.00   30.94
       23   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    0.00    34.38
       24   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    0.00    1.00    37.81
       25   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    -1.00   37.13
       26   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    0.00    41.25
       27   -4.00   27.50   0.25    0.20    0.10    1.00    1.00    1.00    45.38
```

Thanks for any assistance in this .

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ===============================
print(df)

   Quant    Vol
0     13  30.00
1      4  27.50
2    -19  26.00
3     14  23.50
4      4  21.00
5     18  20.00
6     -1  19.00
7     16  18.50
8     -5  18.75
9    -18  19.00


# processing
# ====================================

def func(group):
    # some constants
    par = 0.25
    skew = 0.2
    TS = 0.1
    multi_level_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1], [-1,0,1]], names=['p', 's', 't'])
    # construct dataframe
    frame = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_level_index)
    frame['Quant'] = group['Quant'].values[0]
    frame['Vol'] = group['Vol'].values[0]
    frame = frame.reset_index()
    frame['Scenario'] = np.arange(1, 1+len(frame))
    frame = frame.set_index('Scenario')
    # do calculations
    frame['Mod_Vol'] = frame.Vol*(1+par*frame.p)*(1+skew*frame.s)*(1+TS*frame.t)      
    return frame

# do you really want to groupby on `Vol`
# because I saw there are duplicated value of Vol, say 19.00 on row 6 and 9
# below use groupby on the default integer index, which is equivalent to iterating over each row
result = df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).apply(func).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

          p  s  t  Quant  Vol  Mod_Vol
Scenario                              
1        -1 -1 -1     13   30   16.200
2        -1 -1  0     13   30   18.000
3        -1 -1  1     13   30   19.800
4        -1  0 -1     13   30   20.250
5        -1  0  0     13   30   22.500
6        -1  0  1     13   30   24.750
7        -1  1 -1     13   30   24.300
8        -1  1  0     13   30   27.000
9        -1  1  1     13   30   29.700
10        0 -1 -1     13   30   21.600
...      .. .. ..    ...  ...      ...
18        0  1  1    -18   19   25.080
19        1 -1 -1    -18   19   17.100
20        1 -1  0    -18   19   19.000
21        1 -1  1    -18   19   20.900
22        1  0 -1    -18   19   21.375
23        1  0  0    -18   19   23.750
24        1  0  1    -18   19   26.125
25        1  1 -1    -18   19   25.650
26        1  1  0    -18   19   28.500
27        1  1  1    -18   19   31.350

[270 rows x 6 columns]


# to select scenario 1, use .loc
result.loc[1]


          p  s  t  Quant    Vol  Mod_Vol
Scenario                                
1        -1 -1 -1     13  30.00   16.200
1        -1 -1 -1      4  27.50   14.850
1        -1 -1 -1    -19  26.00   14.040
1        -1 -1 -1     14  23.50   12.690
1        -1 -1 -1      4  21.00   11.340
1        -1 -1 -1     18  20.00   10.800
1        -1 -1 -1     -1  19.00   10.260
1        -1 -1 -1     16  18.50    9.990
1        -1 -1 -1     -5  18.75   10.125
1        -1 -1 -1    -18  19.00   10.260
```

Comment: I have a lot to learn . . you make it look easy my friend.  Thanks again.  John